# Getting different (and incorrect) results runing the same cypher query on identical DB schemas

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, cypher

I'm running the following cypher query on two identical neo4j DB schemas:

```
START dave = node(7)
// dave's friend who lives and attends an event in the same city
MATCH dave-[:FRIEND]-friend-[:LIVES]->city-[:HOSTS]->event<-[:ATTENDS]-friend
RETURN dave.name, friend.name, city.name, event.name;
```

When I run the above query on the DB schema on my local server, I get correct results--a single path:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+ 
| dave.name | friend.name | city.name | event.name   |  
+----------------------------------------------------+ 
| "dave"    | "adam"      | "london"  | "exhibition" | 
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

In fact for each of the 4 persons node(4, 5, 6, 7), adam=node(4) is the only person who lives and attends an event in the same city.

However, when I run the same query [here](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=rkqzww) (on the exact same DB schema as on my local server) I'm getting the following incorrect result:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+ 
| dave.name | friend.name | city.name | event.name   |  
+----------------------------------------------------+ 
| "dave"    | "adam"      | "london"  | "exhibition" | 
| "dave"    | "adam"      | "london"  | "exhibition" | 
| "dave"    | "bill"      | "paris"   | "seminar"    | // bill doesn't attend seminar
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

For other persons instead of dave=node(7), the results [here](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=rkqzww) are also incorrect (extra paths that don't exist).

Comment: Are they both running the same version of neo4j? Also you say that they have the same info, is this a load on both you did, or was it a load on one and a copy over to the other?

Comment: On my computer I'm using v1.8 neo4j, and on the [web console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=rkqzww) I select the same version before running the query. So yes, in both cases I have the same version. Moreover, the query on the web console gives the same result (incorrect as I explained earlier) for all other versions (those older or newer than v1.8). Sorry, @Nicholas the second question in your comment is not clear. Kindly explain.

Comment: How are you loading the data into your systems? You say that they are the same data, but how are you ensuring this?

Comment: @Nicholas - To set up the graph DB, I run this cypher CREATE [query](https://gist.github.com/4165034). As you can see on the [web console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=rkqzww), this is the only data there is; and on my computer I run the CREATE query on an empty DB. So, in both cases there is the same data for the next query which I posted in my question.

Comment: Can you please raise this as an issue in http://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try to separate the match phase into 2, i have never used one parameter name 2 times in one match pattern:

except

```
MATCH dave-[:FRIEND]-friend-[:LIVES]->city-[:HOSTS]->event<-[:ATTENDS]-friend
```

use

```
MATCH dave-[:FRIEND]-friend-[:LIVES]->city-[:HOSTS]->event, event<-[:ATTENDS]-friend
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the first query--it's perfectly legal, and returns the correct (expected) result when run on my local DB server. My question was why the same query gives incorrect results when run on another identical DB schema on the web console [here](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=rkqzww) (returns multiple non-existing paths where only one path exists). Moreover, in both cases I use/set the same version (v1.8) and ensure that the data in the 2 DB's is identical.